# SQL query: choosing only the first word in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and Windows.

I have column data that looks like this:

[image: column info]

Table name: employees

I need to run an SQL query where the result will:

Display only FullName column.

Display ONLY THE FIRST WORD of each name in the column.

What would be the SQL query?

Comment: Please show us what query you have so far and how its results differ from your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all sorts of string functions described here [String operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). One that would work is:

```
select split_part('Adrian Klaver', ' ', 1);
 split_part 
------------
 Adrian

--So in your case
Select split_part("FullName", ' ', 1) from employees;
```